# Teamdrive/Tonido/Syncplicity-like Servers? (like Dropbox)

Tags: file-sharing, document-management, versioning

I've been looking around for dropbox-like server products and so far have found this three:

- http://www.tonido.com (free, no limits)
- http://www.teamdrive.com (free, limited)
- http://www.syncplicity.com (free, limited)

and this how-to, on how to build a dropbox-like service yourself:

- http://fak3r.com/geek/howto-build-your-own-open-source-dropbox-clone/

are there any others?

The problem when looking for stuff like this is that everybody seems to be looking for something different, so while there are a lot of posts here and on other websites about various services/products, only a few of them seem to actually do what I'm looking for. Also some of them seem to be still in development ( http://www.sparkleshare.org ) or in a "private beta" phase ( http://www.aerofs.com ).

The criteria are:

- files should be hosted on my private server
- needs to work over the internet
- needs to have a web interface
- needs to have a way of direct-file-access (like webdav, or dropbox-like, ideally with Windows explorer integration)
- needs to run on Windows (so no iFolder or similar)
- file versioning would be nice (or maybe it can work together with Windows' shadow copies?)
- encrypted transfers would be nice
- some backup functionality would be nice (like a "download everything"-button that packs the files together into a zip-file and provides a download link)

Comment: closed as `not a real question`, `too localized`, and `subjective & argumentative`.

Comment: Such questions are welcome at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com :-)